# How do I remove headers / footers after the first page?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, headers, footers

Our company letterhead has the corporate logo (in the header) and contact information (in the footer) - this format is in a Word 2010 template, and repeats into the second page.

I would like to begin my report with this format, however in ALL the subsequent pages (both even and odd), I do not want to have this header and footer information printed/visible - I would like all subsequent pages (after the Letterhead first page) to be blank A4 pages on the Word 2010 document.

How do I do this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Select the first page header (double click it) and in the design tab select "Different First Page".

[image]

This will make the header and footer specific to the first page. Move to the second page and remove any header/footers there.

Answer (score 0):

select header on other pages and find the **Design Tab** > untick **Different First Page** .. this worked my end